# Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Array. json data

Tags: javascript, json, angular, ionic-framework

JSON data

```
data:[
   {
    assets:[[tool_order_id: "38",order_status_id: "10"]],
    order_info:[id: "1", order_type: "6",check: "1", current_Stage_id: "29"]
},
{
  assets:[tool_order_id: "1",order_status_id: "10"],
    order_info:[id: "2", order_type: "3",check: "1", current_Stage_id: "29"]
},  
{
    assets:[[tool_order_id: "8",order_status_id: "10"]],
    order_info:[id: "3", order_type: "3",check: "1", current_Stage_id: "29"]
},
{
  assets:[tool_order_id: "3",order_status_id: "10"],
    order_info:[id: "4", order_type: "3",check: "1", current_Stage_id: "29"]
}
]
```

if I iterate this I am getting error.
Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.the below is html

```
 <div *ngIf="orders['assets'].length != 0">
 <ion-row *ngFor="let tool of orders['assets']">
 <ion-col col-4>{{ tool.tool_order_id }}</ion-col>
 <ion-col col-4>{{ tool.order_status_id }}</ion-col>
  </ion-row>
<div *ngIf="orders['assets'].length != 0">
 <ion-row *ngFor="let tool of orders['assets']['0']">
 <ion-col col-4>{{ tool.tool_order_id }}</ion-col>
 <ion-col col-4>{{ tool.order_status_id }}</ion-col>
  </ion-row>
```

and in data.ts file store the data in orders
`this.orders = this.data; console.log(this.orders);`
able to display the data in console.

Comment: can you share the code you have written for the ngFor loop?

Comment: `[tool_order_id: "1",order_status_id: "10"]` this is not valid JS array syntax. Are you sure you're dealing with an array and not an Object?

Answer (score 0):

You can do loop inside loop if it coming in console somehow

```
<div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton2" *ngFor="let pChannel  of channels"> 
              <div *ngFor="let channel of pChannel">
              <a class="dropdown-item" (click)="getVouchersByChannelId(channel.channelId)">  
                  {{ channel.channelName }}             
                </a> 
              </div> 
            </div>
```

Comment: I have assets [ [ mydata]] and assets[ mydata] and I need to get both the data in a single variable and display in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
<ion-row *ngFor="let t of data">
<ion-row *ngFor="let tool of t.orders['assets']">
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The data is not in properly formatted. [ ] denotes an array. Inside an array you can't have key value pairs directly, `[tool_order_id: "38",order_status_id: "10"]`. It should be an object `{tool_order_id: "38",order_status_id: "10"}`. First make sure your data is properly formatted.
2. Please get rid of inconsistencies in the data like assets in line 1 is an array of arrays and in line 2 it is an array.

   assets:[[tool_order_id: "38",order_status_id: "10"]],

   assets:[tool_order_id: "1",order_status_id: "10"],